# SQL: Performing UPDATE IGNORE with duplicate removal

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume I have following table, where PRIMARY_KEY is `parent_id, child_id`

```
parent_id | child_id
----------+---------
        1 |        2
        1 |        3
```

I would like to perform a query, which would update the rows and delete possible duplicates, so that following query:

```
UPDATE IGNORE table SET child_id = 2 WHERE child_id = 3;
```

Would result in:

```
parent_id | child_id
----------+---------
        1 |        2
```

I need some kind of general solution so that I could write complex queries which would achieve this.

Comment: There is no duplicate until you define it. Set primary key to `parent_id` and `child_id` to a simple index, or `parent_id+child_id` to be unique. Your going at this from the wrong side, better clean the schema to fit.

Comment: This is not a solution. Even if it is set to UNIQUE, it won't delete the duplicate on update.

Answer (score 1):

If MySQL was supporting modifications of the table from within a trigger on the same table the solution would have been very elegant.

```
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_duplicate BEFORE UPDATE ON table FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE (parent_id, child_id) = (NEW.parent_id, NEW.child_id) > 0) THEN
      DELETE FROM table WHERE (parent_id, child_id) = (OLD.parent_id, OLD.child_id);
    END IF;
  END;
```

Since it does not support such a feature, you might need to change your application logic in order to achieve the same thing, or create a stored procedure for these updates.

Comment: And with stored procedure it would be possible? I am rather looking for some kind of general solution, which I could use as simply as writing "UPDATE IGNORE".

Comment: Of course, just create such a procedure and call it instead of the normal update: SELECT update_without_duplicate(2, 3); You can use the body of the trigger above with little modifications and it will do the job for you. You just need to obtain these OLD values, instead of COUNT(*) and that's all.